# cross scrolling: tableview inside UIpageViewcontroller does not behave properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

In my app, I have a UIPageViewcontroller. Inside the UIPageViewcontroller, I have a Viewcontroller with a table inside of it.

The problem I am having is, when I am scrolling down the table, I can't scroll between pages. unless I lift my finger up. (this also has to make sure that table stops scrolling completely)

I was hoping there would be a more natural way of doing this.[image]

Is there a way to swipe between pages even when your scrolling down the table, without have to lift up your finger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried Instagram, they have same UI as you are trying to achieve.
When I scrolled through Insta posts, I could not Swipe between View Controllers until table scroll stops.

1 option you can do is to reduce the speed of table scroll using following code:

```
self.tableview.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

This code will allow table to stop quickly and hence user can swipe.

Hence, I would say, it is not possible to swipe between view controller unless table scrolling is stopped.